# How do I access the ID of clicked header (h3) with jQuery UI Accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

[The documentation for the jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) gives examples of multiple variations of an h3 and div combination, which become the title and content for one of the accordion buttons.

In my page, I have ID's for every h3, and I would like to access them programmatically when someone clicks one of the accordion buttons. The most obvious approach I see is to register a click listener on h3's and access the event target to pull the HTML ID, perhaps after the accordion call. But I'm a little unclear on whether that solution is the right one.

What is a preferred way of having an event handler tell the HTML ID of the h3 that was used to build the accordion button the user clicked?

Comment: Can you show a minimal representation of the code you're working with, jQuery and HTML?

Answer (score 2):

When creating the accordion you can simply pass an event handler for the activate-event.
This event is triggered after a panel has been activated (after animation completes). See http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

You could do something like this

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
activate: function( event, ui ) {
 if(!ui.newHeader.isEmptyObject()){
  alert(ui.newHeader.attr('id'))
 }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will assign the `id` of the clicked `h3` element to a variable. This also should account for dynamic content, as it uses `on` instead of just `click`.

```
$("h3").on("click", function(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

If that doesn't work, however, for dynamic content, you might want to try something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "h3", function(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: Why not simply use `this.id`?

Comment: Honestly? I'm used to doing it this way, and I may or may not have but definitely not known about `this.id`.